# android scrollview is not working on recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used recyclerview in my project. The recyclerview is inside the scrollview. When I am scrolling the scrollview is not working but the recyclerview scrolling. How I can stop scroll the recyclerview and continue scrolling on scrollview. Please give me some idea.. Please refer my file here:

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.foofys.fitblink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_bgimg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/dark_blue"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
                app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/parent_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/bg_img"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/headerbackground" />

                    <com.foofys.support.SlidingTabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/mypager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android scroll view is not intend to work in recycler view because recycler view has its own scroll.

Comment: i can't see any RecyclerView in your xml file.

Comment: am sorry .. this is my main_activity file.. i this file i using viewpager.. in my fragment_one.xml file i am using recyclerview.. Please refer play newsstand app.. that's my aim to develop

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends RecyclerView{
public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

boolean expanded = false;

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded()) {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}}
```

edit ans,

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
```

Comment: copy this code into your package. then simply use this class into xml where your recyclerview used.

Comment: and recyclerview.setexpanded(true) set to recyclerview. thats it.

Comment: sorry am not understand.. i used this ExpandableHeightListView class my xml layout.. then how i can use recyclerview.setexpanded(true)  ?? i commented recyclerview from my java class..

Comment: will u pls tell me how  can use this ExpandableHeightListView class in my own java class.. i took this id like mListView = (ExpandableHeightListView)view.findviewbyid(R.id.my_recycle_view); now i am facing nullpointerexception in public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)